# Deleted questions affect the rules of downvoting on answers?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Recently I Downvoted on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194004/how-to-change-variable-in-another-file-if-form-is-submitted/57194124#57194124) because I found that is not an answer (that is comment) & I flagged that answer as `Not an answer`

By default, I lost my 1 reputation due to Downvote on answer

After some time , the user deleted it's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194004/how-to-change-variable-in-another-file-if-form-is-submitted), answers are also deleted by default when question is deleted. But I couldn't gain my losted 1 reputation when answer is deleted with deleted question
[image: Pic of deleted question and answer]
[image: Reputation change]
Deleted questions affect the rules of downvoting on answers?

Comment: If you go to reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10273906/rk003?tab=reputation you should see a *+1 removed* event for that answer. At least that is what I see for an answer I downvoted that later got removed. I'm not sure if those events are only added once per hour or so. We could blame caching in that case.

Comment: No it's showing `There were no net reputation changes on this day`

Comment: You can see a more detailed view at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: It is showing `-- 2019-07-25 rep 0     = 352` but see https://imgur.com/2yakv78

Comment: I edited my question I added pic of reputation change on today

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/